# сбор значений из разных строк/столбцов в одну строку по уникальному идентификатору

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть лог программы (пишется просто строкой, без сепараторов Оо) - данный лог собрал в датафрейм 17 столбцов >25000 строк. (самый маленький лог)
В логе записаны состояние процессов в различное время, уникальный идентификатор - id процесса. На разных этапах жизни процесса он генерирует различные статусы.

```
    ID  status1 status2 status3 status4
0   1   ok          
1   2               
2   3                       ok  
3   1              ok       
4   3   ok          
5   1              ok       
6   2              ok               ok
7   3               
8   1                               ok
9   3                               ok
10  3               
11  2
```

Код датафрейма для примера.

```
data = {'ID':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2],
  'status1':['ok','','','','ok','','','','','','',''],
  'status2':['','','','ok','','ok','ok','','','','',''],
  'status3':['','','ok','','','','','','','','',''],
  'status4':['','','','','','','ok','','ok','ok','','']}
ttf = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Хочу получить датафрейм вида:

```
    ID  status1 status2 status3 status4
0   1   ok        ok             ok
1   2             ok      ok
2   3   ok                ok     ok
```

Одна строка ID и все заполненные статусы которые есть. По каждому id.
Сижу, туплю - укажите нужный путь =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто группируете по `ID` и берёте максимум по каждой колонке в группе. Строка`'ok'` считается больше, чем пустая строка `''` (любая не пустая строка больше, чем пустая), поэтому это сработает.

```
ttf.groupby('ID').max()
```

| ID | status1 | status2 | status3 | status4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ok | ok |  | ok |
| 2 |  | ok |  | ok |
| 3 | ok |  | ok | ok |

А если вдруг статус будет не один, а разные, и хочется видеть все эти статусы списком без повторов, то могу предложить вот такую хитрую аггрегацию вместо `.max`:

```
.agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(filter(None, x))) or '')
```